# Can a Windows service stop itself?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I have a Windows service whose startup type is automatic, but I want to do some checks when the service starts, and have the service stop automatically if these checks fail.

How can I do this?  My service is written in C#.

Answer (score 20):

You can call the `Stop` method on your `ServiceBase` class. See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.stop.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Isn't this an invalid scenario since the stack will unwind from OnStop  back to the service which is still running?

`If the service reports to the SCM that the service has stopped before all threads have exited, it is possible that the SCM will interpret this as a contradiction. This might result in a state where the service cannot be stopped or restarted.`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/multithreaded-services

Comment: It does work, @andrew.rockwell. Calling `OnStop` does not imply that the service will report that it has stopped before all threads have exited. Did you read the msdn link from my answer?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) and call .stop.

```
ServiceController sc= new ServiceController(service);
sc.Stop();
```