# Log Process execution

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to restart a windows service from the same windows service with this piece of code

```
var proc = new Process();
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();

psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.FileName = "cmd.exe";
psi.Arguments = "/C net stop \"EmailService-3.1.0\ && net start \"EmailService-3.1.0\"";
psi.LoadUserProfile = false;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
proc.StartInfo = psi;
```

It is not working and I have no idea why, is there anything I can do to log or determine what is happening or get the output of what is happening when the net stop command is called?

Comment: There are [other ways](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770206/can-a-windows-service-stop-itself) to stop the service from within

Comment: I am trying to do this from the same windows service.

Comment: Did you see the link? It's not really highlighted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770206/can-a-windows-service-stop-itself

Comment: I want to restart and not stop.  I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the output of the net stop command, but as per TomT's comment, this seems a very roundabout way to restart a service.

```
psi.Arguments = "/C net stop \"EmailService-3.1.0\" > C:\\svclog.txt "; //&& net start \"EmailService-3.1.0\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see a missing quotation mark after the name of your service in the stop command. Otherwise it can be a permission issue. Maybe the user with whom your service has logged in does not have enough privileges to stop a service.