# is it .Net Safe to stop a windows service it self?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to create a Windows Service (Service1) runs and stops itself. Here is the basic code for this:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        If SetConfigVariables() Then
        Action()
        Else
        'Log Error
         End If
    End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
    'Log End of service

End Sub

Private Sub Action()
    'Do Stuff
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000) 'Pause for 3 seconds
    Dim oSvcController As New ServiceController("ServiceName1")
    oSvcController.Stop()
End Sub
```

In this code, the service starts, does some stuff and then stops itself. Is this a good way to go about stopping itself?

Comment: There is no indication in [Can a Windows service stop itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11770206/1115360) that there is any problem with that.

Comment: so when I am running the code... it just hangs... it doesn't fire the OnStop function. When I go try to manually stop it, I get an error stating the service isn't accepting commands..i kill the process via the Task Manager... any ideas as to why this is not stopping my service?

Comment: Could it be hanging in the "Log End of service" code?

Comment: Can I ask, what is the purpose of a service that stops it self?  Can't it just be a standard application that runs on start up?